# BigQuery Update Query with Joining on Multiple Tables Very Confused On My WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, sql-update

I am trying to do an UPDATE query in BigQuery. My aim is to multiply each of the rows in the DeliveredForecastTest table, by the scalar value in the FLA table, where the SummaryFormatID = FLA SummaryFormatID and the DateID is in the correct week number in the dates table. Hance why I'm joining a number of table before doing the UPDATE. I don't understand how I set my WHERE clause in this case.

The Table I am attempting to update is "DeliveredForecastTest" which has three Columns:
OfficeID, TrafficFormatID, DateID, Volume

the ID fields are foreign keys into other tables.

I also have a table "FLA" with the following Schema:
Year, Week, Scalar, SummaryFormatID

I am trying to join my tables together (I'm doing joins on 4 tables involving tblDates and tblTrafficFormat)

tblDates has a schema:
DateID, FinancialYear, WeekNo ....

tblTrafficFormatDeliveredDetailed has schema:
TrafficFormatID, SummaryFormatID ....

The following query I have come up with is:

```
  UPDATE `DeliveredForecastTest` Test
  SET Test.Volume = Test.Volume *
  (
    SELECT cast(FLA.Scalar As Int64)
    FROM `DeliveredForecastTest` TableRawDatabaseSlim
    inner join `tblTrafficFormatDeliveredDetailed` as tblTrafficFormat
      on TableRawDatabaseSlim.TrafficFormatID = tblTrafficFormat.TrafficFormatID
    inner join `tblDates` as tblDates
      on TableRawDatabaseSlim.DateID = tblDates.DateID
    inner join `FLA` as FLA
      on FLA.Year = tblDates.FinancialYear 
      and FLA.Week = tblDates.WeekNo 
      and FLA.SummaryFormatID = tblTrafficFormat.SummaryFormatID
  )
 #DONT KNOW WHAT MY WHERE CLAUSE SHOULD BE SINCE DeliveredForecastTest ARE JUST FOREIGN KEYS
```